# Why Time Picker is not showing in android?

Tags: android, datetimepicker

Time picker is not showing , i don't know and what is going wrong. I think the problem is in case statement , i don't know what i should write in case statement to show time picker, Here is my source code. please tell me what i am missing here?

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener{
private Button btnStart,btnCalculate,btnTime;
static final int DATE_START_DIALOG_ID = 0;

private int mhourOfDay=0;
private int mminute=0;
boolean is24HourView2;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnTime=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    btnTime.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
        case TIME_START_DIALOG_ID:

    }


    return null;
}


//Time picker
private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener mTimeSetListener
        =new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {


        mhourOfDay=hourOfDay;
        mminute=minute;

         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"hourOfDay is="+mhourOfDay+"minute="+mminute,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
};


public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.button2:
            showDialog(TIME_START_DIALOG_ID);
            break;
       default:
            break;
   }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return the `TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener` inside Switch statement:

```
    @Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
        case TIME_START_DIALOG_ID:
            return new TimePickerDialog(this,mTimeSetListener, mHour, mMinute, false);
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @rafsanahmad007